# AWS CLI S3 get object tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to get object tags by AWS CLI. Is it possible to display all object tags? Or even display the value of a specific key from tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the command `aws s3api get-object-tagging --bucket bucketname --key objectkey`. For example

```
➜  ~ aws s3 ls helloworld-20181029141519-deployment
2018-11-24 07:19:11          0 hello.world

➜  ~ aws s3api get-object-tagging --bucket helloworld-20181029141519-deployment --key hello.world
{
    "TagSet": [
        {
            "Value": "1",
            "Key": "tagged"
        },
        {
            "Value": "bar",
            "Key": "foo"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can use a [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/) expression to filter the result set.

```
➜  ~ aws s3api get-object-tagging --bucket helloworld-20181029141519-deployment --key hello.world --query "TagSet[?Key=='foo']"
[
    {
        "Value": "bar",
        "Key": "foo"
    }
]
```